# Lenovo Thinkpad E330 wireless hardware blocked

Tags: wireless, lenovo, thinkpad

I have an issue with freshly installed Ubuntu 14.04. I have downloaded
and installed firmware to (iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode) and everything seems ok, but I still cant make it work. It says that WiFi is turned off by physical switch but it is not. My friend advised me to post the output of these files and ask question here.

### lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
```

### lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
bnep                   19624  2 
rfcomm                 69160  0 
bluetooth             391136  10 bnep,rfcomm
nls_iso8859_1          12713  1 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     46368  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    65580  1 
arc4                   12608  2 
iwldvm                232285  0 
mac80211              626557  1 iwldvm
uvcvideo               80885  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         40664  1 uvcvideo
videodev              134688  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
intel_rapl             18773  0 
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    14205  0 
intel_powerclamp       14705  0 
coretemp               13435  0 
crct10dif_pclmul       14289  0 
crc32_pclmul           13113  0 
snd_hda_intel          56451  3 
ghash_clmulni_intel    13216  0 
cryptd                 20359  1 ghash_clmulni_intel
snd_hda_codec         192906  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102099  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
thinkpad_acpi          81013  1 
nvram                  14411  1 thinkpad_acpi
parport_pc             32701  0 
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
ppdev                  17671  0 
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30144  1 snd_seq_midi
joydev                 17381  0 
serio_raw              13462  0 
snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
iwlwifi               169932  1 iwldvm
snd_timer              29482  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
lp                     17759  0 
snd                    69322  18 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,thinkpad_acpi,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
parport                42348  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
lpc_ich                21080  0 
rtsx_pci_ms            18151  0 
memstick               16966  1 rtsx_pci_ms
mei_me                 18627  0 
mei                    82276  1 mei_me
cfg80211              484040  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
wmi                    19177  0 
i915                  784207  3 
soundcore              12680  1 snd
video                  19476  1 i915
drm_kms_helper         55071  1 i915
mac_hid                13205  0 
drm                   303102  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 i915
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         23274  0 
r8169                  67581  0 
psmouse               106714  0 
mii                    13934  1 r8169
ahci                   25819  3 
libahci                32716  1 ahci
rtsx_pci               46202  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
```

### rfkill list

```
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

### ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3c:97:0e:24:ee:50  
          inet addr:192.168.1.101  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::3e97:eff:fe24:ee50/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7969 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9054 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3167428 (3.1 MB)  TX bytes:4028329 (4.0 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:11006 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11006 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:6297520 (6.2 MB)  TX bytes:6297520 (6.2 MB)
```

### iwconfig

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

I have checked BIOS settings and it looks correct. I am not IT
specialist so let me know if you need any further information or logs.
Usual solutions found on Google did not help and often I don't
fully understand them.

thank you in advance!

Comment: Does the wireless key combination, Fn+F9 perhaps, change: rfkill list all?

Comment: Did you solved it? if yes how?

Answer (score 1):

Your Wireless LAN is hard blocked. To unblock it -

`sudo rfkill unblock all`

Comment: this command neither helps :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no hardware switch on this particular model, just a key on the keyboard which activates the wireless feature.

Press F9 to enable or disable the wireless feature.

Comment: Pressing F9 only changes the "soft blocked", but "hard blocked" still remains with its "yes"and doesn't change at all...